# How to add options to a launcher?

Tags: 13.04, kubuntu

I have a launcher for a program, anyway I'd like to start that program with a command line option.
eg.

```
eclipse -e
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run in a terminal

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop
```

Find the `Exec` field and set it to `eclipse -e`

Save the file and exit Gedit and the Terminal.

EDIT

As mentioned as a comment, the file can as well as be copied to `~/.local/share/applications` and edited there doing the same change.